# What clef is this? (Baroque, Vivaldi)

Tags: notation, baroque-period, clefs

What is this clef in Vivaldi RV281? This is the only source of the concerto is available ( at least without buying it, which is the manuscript). The piece did have a few weird clefs like an octave bass clef once for one of the violin sections, but nothing too unusual. His handwriting is pretty hard to read sometimes, and I am just plain confused about what it is. The section that played the stave was the viola section originally, and it switched to this clef later on. I remember seeing something like it before, but I forgot what it was, looks kind of like the French 18th-century clefs, but neither that nor alto clef sounded right or true at least to the recording I am using, which is essentially the same all the other ones, just a semitone lower (for baroque-interpretation, although I don't really care), here is the section in the youtube video I'm using and below it the picture of the clef in question,

. [image: The clef in question.]

Comment: There was a small missing sharp causing this problem, I apologize for asking the question, but I would still like  to know is this some sort of this old french alto clefs because it seems so, or is another form of alto clef?

Comment: It's just a regular alto clef.

Comment: I agree that Vivaldi is hard to read from the manuscript. With Vivaldi manuscripts, I know which notes are where, but the note value is hard to make out because sometimes the sixteenths look like eighths and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be drawn a bit scribbly but it certainly looks like a K-clef, (a stylistic variant of the C-clef). In particular it's an alto clef (which makes sense for viola).

[image: K-Clef with quavers]

So those first few notes in the image are at the pitch of E above middle C.
(With the two treble G-clefs directly above, the chord made (E, G, B) is an E minor chord in close position.

Comment: It doesn't even look like a K-clef, just a regular C-clef with the top loop faint or missing. The bottom loop is quite clear.

Answer (score 6):

It looks a bit like a hand-written C-clef. Reading as such seems to make sense harmonically.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an Ut3 clef: C (Do) e.g Ut is on the 3rd line.

So I read 4xE 8th twice and 4xB 8th twice. As ttw points out this makes sense harmonically: first chord is  B G E (from top to bottom): G major chord G-B-E.

Comment: 'G major chord G-B-*E*'?